# Laravel cache forget does not update cache

Tags: laravel, caching

I am using the cache to determine if a file is being processed, to prevent simultaneous access. I have the following 3 functions:

```php
public function cacheKey(): string
{
    return "uploads.$this->filename";
}

public function checkSingleton(): bool
{
    if (cache($this->cacheKey())) return true;
    cache([$this->cacheKey() => 1], now()->addHours(2));
    
    return false;
}

public function clearSingleton(): void
{
    cache()->forget($this->cacheKey());
}
```

When I run them in a script, I am able to set the cache, but not clear it. Oddly, when I do the same from `php artisan tinker`, it does forget the key as expected.

I have tried using the helper (e.g. `cache()->forget()`) as well as the fully qualified name (i.e. `Cache::forget()`). When I check the database, I can see that it is creating the key, but not removing it.

#### EDIT

I have also tried using atomic locks as suggested. Again, I am able to create the lock, but not remove it.

```
public function cacheKey(): string
{
  return "uploads.$this->filename";
}

public function checkSingleton(): bool
{
  return !Cache::lock($this->cacheKey(),60*60)->get();
}

public function clearSingleton(): void
{
  Cache::lock($this->cacheKey())->forceRelease();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about why it is not clearing, but do not use a cache for this, use an [atomic lock](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/cache#atomic-locks) as the cache could still give you access but 1 line later it is used, an atomic lock will always prevent this inconsistency from happening. And one more tip, do follow PSR, never do `if (condition) result`, always use `{ }`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to atomic locks. I switched the code to use locks and I have exactly the same issue. I can create the lock, but I can not remove it. Again, when I use tinker, it works as expected.

Comment: Okay, I have a new question now, how are you running this code? I read you mentioned a script, and that is not working, but works on tinker, what do you mean with script? How are you running this code/class having this code?

Comment: It is part of a controller that is responding to a user request from a web page

Comment: So is it just in a controller being run when a route is acessed?